# Recording heart rate from a Bluetooth heart rate monitor

Tags: android, bluetooth, fitness

I have a heart rate monitor strap. It transmits my heart rate, using Bluetooth Smart and Ant+. I want an app on my Android phone or tablet that can connect to this, and display and record my heart rate.

Some features I would like:

- Display current heart rate
- Display minimum, maximum and average heart rate, for the whole activity
- Display a graph of the heart rate over time
- Works without GPS, ie indoors
- Export in a standard format, eg CSV or TCX
- Preferably simple, efficient and reliable - maybe options to adjust the recording frequency to save battery
- Price: free would be good, though I may pay a few pound for something that works well

Comment: Hard to tell if you don't specify which exact model you use, as those gadgets often use specific protocols. My first idea was to check with [Gadgetbridge](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/), but I don't remember a "strap" mentioned there. Mustn't be a show-stopper, though, as new devices being added every now and then.

Comment: Specifically a Mio Fuse. But there's a variety of similar things from other brands.The Bluetooth LE specification defines a "Heart Rate Profile", so they should be compatible with that.